# When importing a CSV from Google Storage into Google SQL is there a way to skip the first row?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

From https://console.cloud.google.com/sql/instances/ select an instance, then select "Import", then select "CSV".

I don't see any option to skip the first row.

The LOAD statement can do it, I just don't see that option in the Web UI.

Comment: Is there an update for 2018?

Comment: and for 2019? I am trapped in this situation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not something we currently support in the Cloud Console or the API.

For the time being, you can use `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` to execute a load from a different machine but that won't be as efficient. Does that work for you?

Alternatively, you could manually remove the header from the file. I realize that's less ideal than having the import automatically ignore it.